# Closing Mongoose connection with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a server up and running with no errors being thrown.  I am streaming data from a mongodb.  When the data is done streaming I want to call 'close' and then disconnect the mongo database.

Below is the code that I have.  When I try to connect to the server a first request succeeds but any additional requests fail.

When I attempted to check if the mongodb was being disconnected I found out that it wasn't.

How do you use a `mongoose.connection.close()` and when will it fail?

```
var http = require('http')
  , url = require('url')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , server, n;

server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname.slice(0, 4);
  n = url.parse(request.url).pathname.slice(5);

  // connect to mongo
  mongoose.set('debug', true);
  mongoose.connect('localhost', 'lotsOfNumber');
  mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('connection error: ' + err);
  });

  mongoose.connection.on('open',function() {

    var stuff = mongoose.model('numbersHere', new Schema({serialNumber: Number}, {safe: true}));

    switch (path) {

      case '/slq':

        var stream = stuff.find({}).limit(1).skip(n).sort('field value').stream();

        stream.on('error', function(err) {
          console.error("Error trying to stream from collection:" + err);
        });

        stream.on('data', function(doc) {
          response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
          response.write(doc.value.toString() + '\n', 'utf8');
          response.end();
        });

        stream.on('close', function() {
          mongoose.connection.close();
          mongoose.connection.on('close', function() {console.log('closed');});
        });

        break;

      default:
        console.log('nothing');
        mongoose.connection.close();
        break;
    }
  });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: FWIW the problem went away when removing `mongoose.connection` and instead used `var db = mongoose.connect('localhost', 'm101', {server: {poolSize: 1}}).connection;
  db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Could not connect to mongo server'));`.  By assigning the mongoose.connection to db and avoiding the `on('open'...)` mongoose did close the database

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've always used a pattern like:

```
mongoose.connect('localhost', 'lotsOfNumber');
...
mongoose.disconnect();
```

But you shouldn't be connecting and disconnecting on each request like you are.  Instead, connect during your application start up and disconnect during shutdown.

`mongoose.connect` opens a pool of connections that concurrent requests can share.

Comment: Thanks.  I moved the db connection outside the `http.createServer`.

Comment: "But you shouldn't be connecting and disconnecting on each request like you are. Instead, connect during your application start up and disconnect during shutdown."

That's what I was looking for :)